# Magento2 - Switch to right website on login

Tags: magento-2.1, login, user

We've recently migrated a company to a new `Magento2` installation and imported the users across two different websites; one local and one for `World`. These website only differ in the payment provider options and tax config.

Now the client just asked why no one was able to login to the site. It appears that you can't login to the `World`-website when you're on the `Local`-website.

Because the two sites are virtually identical it's very confusing this way. I wonder if it would be possible to switch to the right website when a `user logs` in, no matter from what website in the system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it ourselves by deploying different domainnames for both websites, and wrote a custom plugin to check if the user exists in either website, and if so, redirect to that site.

As far as I know this is the only solution for this specific issue.